# Documentation topic classification using word2vec

Tags: python, classification, text-mining, word2vec

I want to build a model that can classification news into specific categorize. As i imagine that i will put all the selected train paper into specific label category then you word2vec for training and generate model?. I wonder does it possible?. 
I have try some small example to build vocab in gensim but it keep telling me that word doesn't exist in vocab.. I'm so confuse.

```
 randomTxt = 'loop is good. loop infinity is not good. they are good at some point.'
x = randomTxt.split() #This finds words in the document
a = Counter(x)
print x
w1 = 'so'
model1 = Word2Vec(randomTxt,min_count=0) 
print model1.wv['loop']
```

I wonder if anyone have idea or know how to build from the beginning dataset can help me with this ? Or maybe some documentation is good.
I have read this docs: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html
but as i follow like above, it keep telling me loop doesn't exist in vocabulary word2vec build.

Comment: the `gensim` `Word2Vec` class takes an iterable of *sentences* and *words* tokenized. So you need to pass it something like `[['this', 'is','the', 'first', 'sentence'], ['this', 'is', 'the','second','sentence']]`. Instead, you've passed it a string.

Comment: I have put Word2Vec using x variable that split() already but it still doesn't work. Or do you know any tool to separate the string? Because i want to pass news to data.

Comment: `.split` will (poorly) tokenize the *words*. You need *sentences*.

Comment: FWIW, that's exactly what my wikimark project does. Study the code, it's straigth forward (but it takes time to train), see https://github.com/amirouche/wikimark/